# Microsoft Word Document Versions

Tags: microsoft-word-2010, microsoft-word-2003

In Microsoft Word 2003, it was possible to store different Versions of a Document inside the Document itself (File -> Versions.. or check [here](http://www.informit.com/articles/article.aspx?p=433386) -> Chapter Implementing Versions).
Somehow, I'm missing this feature in 2010. Is it still available or was that feature kicked out of Word?

Comment: http://www.nirmaltv.com/2009/07/22/how-to-manage-document-versions-in-word-2010/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sorry to have to bring you the bad news, but it's been a while since MS did away with this feature. In the recent releases of Word, the only such option is for recovery if word crashes in between; in this case you can go to: [File -> Info -> Versions] to access the unsaved work.

Comment: Is there a reason why this feature got removed?

Comment: I can't really give an authoritative answer to that, but according to TechNet.com, this feature was discontinued due to versioning capabilities built into Microsoft SharePoint Services.

Ref:http://www.ehow.com/info_8744213_happened-versioning-word-2007.html